# Multiple similar Class and return text

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
function() {
    return $('.labels').text();
}
```

```html
<div class="answer">
    <span class="labels short-label">I am moving house</span>
    <span class="labels">I want to free up my money</span>
    <span class="labels">I have inherited the property </span>
    <span class="labels short-label">Other</span>
</div>
```

I want to return text every individual class, I have written jQuery unfortunately does not return individual text.

Comment: Are you asking for the function to return an array of strings, each string being one of the four texts?

Answer (score 2):

If you want get only "I am moving house" :

Use this Code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var txt = $(".labels").eq(0).text();

    alert(txt); // return txt;

})
```

Final code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="answer">
       <span class="labels short-label">I am moving house</span>
       <span class="labels">I want to free up my money</span>
       <span class="labels">I have inherited the property </span>
       <span class="labels short-label">Other</span>
    </div>
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        var txt = $(".labels").eq(0).text();

        alert(txt); // return txt;

    })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you don't need to do **B** since jquery will give you concatenated text of all those jquery object that has been selected by the class. but I believe the OP wanted to achieve the **A**

Comment: ehsan, I want track single element "I am moving house", Currently giveing all the text together

Comment: @MargubAlam , you want get "I am moving house" only ?

Comment: @MargubAlam , I updated my answer.if help you Mark it please.